# Text instead of numeric values in Y axis on a Scatter chart - QlikView

Tags: scatter-plot, qlikview

According to http://www.learnallbi.com/scatter-chart-in-qlikview/ , a Scatter chart in QlikView is "Scatter chart is very useful in displaying the relationship between 2 numeric values over a dimension."

Now i'm wondering, if I have a column with text values that are either "High" or "Low". Can they be in a y-axis of a scatter chart? like this [scatter chart with string/text values on Y axis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqqIQ.png)

I've tried for a while, but it doesnt seems to be working, or maybe Im just doing it wrong..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the "Grid Chart" type?

Comment: It is possible with scatter chart but it requires you to use one chart on top the other - bit complicated to get it to sync..but possible.
Basically, build you scatter chart (Y axis should be numbers range that represent the distance between high and low). the second chart (or text box) only shows the labels high and low, and then covers the Y axis of the first chart...hope this helps